# Django - how can I make a cell in a table in the admin interface editable only if it is null?

Tags: django, django-admin

I know I can make columns editable through `admin.py` by using the `list_editable` tuple.  But I want more control than that.  If a value has been set, then I don't want it to be editable.  But if a value has not been set and is still null, then I would like the cell to be editable with a drop-down list of choices via the foreign key.  That is all.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [ModelAdmin.get_form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_form) to add the field to the `readonly_fields` when not null:

```
def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
    form = super(MyModelAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
    if obj.my_field and 'my_field' not in self.readonly_fields:
        self.readonly_fields = self.readonly_fields + ('my_field', ) 
    return form
```

Comment: Thanks, but this only works in the admin change view.  I'm only interested in getting this to work from the main admin table view where items can be set as editable or not in each row.

Comment: a refinement on my question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21974827/django-how-can-i-make-a-cell-in-a-table-in-the-admin-inline-interface-editab