# Django - how can I make a cell in a table in the admin *changelist* interface editable only if it is null?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I would like my data to be editable inline in the Django admin page.  However, I only want some fields columns in each row to be editable.  These columns will change for each row.  Basically, I want a dropdown choice to be displayed if the value in a certain cell is null.  If it is not null, then I don't want it to be editable and would like it to be readonly.

`models.py`:

```
class Size(models.Model):
    size = models.CharField(max_length=20, primary_key=True)

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, primary_key=True)
    size = models.ForeignKey(Size, null=False)

class Pamphlet(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, primary_key=True)
    size = models.ForeignKey(Size, null=True)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, null=True)
```

`admin.py`:

```
class PamphletAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Pamphlet
    list_editable = ('size','book')
    list_display = ('title', 'size', 'book',)

    def get_changelist_form(self, request, **kwargs):
        return PamphletChangeListForm
```

`forms.py`:

```
class PamphletChangeListForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PamphletChangeListForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        instance = kwargs.get('instance')
        if instance:
            self.fields['book'].queryset = Book.objects.filter(
                size=instance.size
            )
            if instance.size is not None:
                self.fields['size'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = 'readonly'
```

This setup is not working for me.  The `size` shows as editable in the changelist form even when it is not null.  Also - what have I failed to understand?

Comment: Are you trying to do this in the changelist or in the pamphlet edit page? Offhand I can tell you that there's something off with your admin classes - have a pamphlet admin with an inline model for pamphlets doesn't fit the model relationships you've shown. A book admin class with an inline model for pamphlets might.

Comment: I'm trying to do this in the changelist. I thought that the inline referred to the changelist, actually.  I thought that "inline" meant "the form that appears in each line of the table".

Comment: Nope - inlines are for the edit page, so you can (using this example) edit a book and all the pamphlets that relate to it simultaneously. I'll add an answer showing how I'd handle this in the changelist.

Answer (score 1):

If your field uses an `input` element, such as a `TextField`, add the `readonly` attribute to the field's widget's `attrs` dict in the changelist form's `__init__` method. Something like this:

```
class PamphletChangeListForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PamphletChangeListForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        instance = kwargs.get('instance')
        if instance:
            self.fields['book'].queryset = Book.objects.filter(
                size=instance.size
            )
            if instance.size is not None:
                self.fields['size'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = 'readonly'
```

That won't protect you against a malicious user faking post data - for that you'd need to customize your admin further. But if you have malicious users on your admin you have bigger problems.

If your field uses a `select` element, you have to change it more - `select` attributes don't have `readonly` as a supported attribute. Instead, you'll want a hidden input with the unchanging value, and a text representation so the user can see what the setting is. Django does not include such a widget, but you can define your own:

```
class LabeledHiddenInput(forms.widgets.HiddenInput):
    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        base_output = super(LabeledHiddenInput, self).render(name, value, attrs)
        if value:
            return base_output + unicode(value)
        else:
            return base_output
```

You might need more careful escaping or even some HTML formatting, this is just a quick example. Check the source code for the built in widgets if you need more examples.

Then you can use that widget instead of the default select:

```
        if instance.size is not None:
            self.fields['size'].widget = LabeledHiddenInput()
```

Comment: Thanks, I've made the edit to my question.  I'm greatly simplifying my actual model to focus on the issue, so a couple typos crept in. Your solution apparently doesn't work, however. It would be great if I could use something like the `ModelAdmin.get_readonly_fields(request, obj=None)` that is described here to work: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields

Comment: `get_readonly_fields` only affects edit pages, not the changelist. If you do use inlines somewhere, it'll be relevant. I can't debug further regarding the changelist solution without more information than "it doesn't work" - the first thing I'd suggest is checking the HTML to see if the `readonly` attribute is present.

Comment: Yes, I can find the read only attribute in the HTML: e.g.: `<select id="id_form-98-size" name="form-98-size" readonly="readonly"><option value="1">1</option>[etc]</select>`, but the changelist page looks exactly the same, and the widget with all the dropdown options is there and appears to function.

Comment: Oh, right. `readonly` only works on `input` elements, not `select`. Unfortunately, the solution for `select` is a little more complicated - you need to entirely replace the widget, and there isn't a built in widget that does the right thing so you have to define your own. I'll update.